# @solana/web3.js subscribe to incoming tokens

Tags: node.js, callback, web3js, solana, solana-web3js

I want to recieve callback when I receive tokens on some account in nodeJS.
This code work properly, but only for SOL. How to do the same for USDT in solana or for any token?

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
(async () => {
  const publicKey = new web3.PublicKey(wallet);
  const solanaConnection = new web3.Connection(httpsNode, {
    wsEndpoint: wssNode,
  });
  solanaConnection.onLogs(
    publicKey,
    (logs, context) => console.log("Updated account info: ", logs),
    "confirmed"
  );
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do essentially the same thing, but instead of using `publicKey`, you should use the USDT associated token account address for that wallet, e.g.

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const splToken = require("@solana/spl-token");
(async () => {
  const walletPublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(wallet);
  const usdtMint = new web3.PublicKey("Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB");
  const publicKey = splToken.getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(usdtMint, walletPublicKey);
  const solanaConnection = new web3.Connection(httpsNode, {
    wsEndpoint: wssNode,
  });
  solanaConnection.onLogs(
    publicKey,
    (logs, context) => console.log("Updated account info: ", logs),
    "confirmed"
  );
})();
```